# How can I set night mode

Tags: android-studio

I want to set night mode in my app. this should be as; I want to change mode from day to night on 7:00 pm and set it back to day mode at 7:am. how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When a user opens your app you can just check the time with the date library in your application class or you main class and based on that set the theme